# How To Check CheckBox From Multiple CheckBoxes On WebPage Using Data Provider(Excel) In Selenium WebDriver with JAVA

Tags: java, checkbox, selenium-webdriver, testng-dataprovider

Scenario : I am currently automating a form where I am passing all input from excel. It includes textboxes ,checkboxes datepicker etc.
Form includes total 15 checkboxes. Now I want my script  to check 1 checkbox which is mentioned in excel. I am using TestNG and Apache POI for it. 
Here is what I have done to get it :

```
public void EventCreation1(String EventName, String EventTagLine,String EventOrganization,String City,String State,String Country, String EventCategory ,String EventDescription,String Name,String EmailID,String Contact){
    driver.get("WEBPAGE URL");  
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='eventName']")).sendKeys(EventName);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='eventTagLine']")).sendKeys(EventTagLine);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='organizerName']")).sendKeys(EventOrganization);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='eventCity']")).sendKeys(City);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='eventState']")).sendKeys(State);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='eventCountry']")).sendKeys(Country);
    //For Category
    List<WebElement> Checkbox = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
    for(int i=0; i<Checkbox.size();i++ ){
        WebElement El =Checkbox.get(i);     
        String id =El.getAttribute("value");
        if(id.equals(EventCategory)){
            El.click();
        }
    }
}
```

Here // String EventCategory is the Checkbox option I am passing as parameter from excel.

Could you please help in this what is wrong here?

HTML Tag:

```
<div class="section colm colm9">
    <div class="frm-row">
        <div class="section colm colm4">
            <div class="option-group">
                <label class="option option-blue block">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="eventType[]" value="TechFest">
                    <span class="checkbox"></span> TechFest
                </label>
                <label class="option option-blue block spacer-t10">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="eventType[]" value="Cultural Fest">
                    <span class="checkbox"></span> Cultural Fest
                </label>
                <label class="option option-blue block spacer-t10">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="eventType[]" value="Management Fest">
                    <span class="checkbox"></span> Management Fest
                </label>
                <label class="option option-blue block spacer-t10">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="eventType[]" value="Sports Fest">
                    <span class="checkbox"></span> Sports Fest
                </label>
                <label class="option option-blue block spacer-t10">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="eventType[]" value="Workshop">
                    <span class="checkbox"></span> Workshop
                </label>
            </div><!-- end .option-group section -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you facing any error ?

Comment: Thanks Narendra for looking into it. Yes I am not able to click on checkbox using:   for(int i=0; i<Checkbox.size();i++ ){
        WebElement El =Checkbox.get(i);     
        String id =El.getAttribute("value");
        if(id.equals(EventCategory)){
            El.click();
        } This is just not clicking on any of the checkbox.
    }
}

Comment: String id is taking all values of checkbox and comparing it with single value from EventCategory,